# How to implement a menu slider similar to Telerik's TeamPulse?

Tags: javascript, menu, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

In looking at several ways of laying out an application, I have settled on the layout the Telerik team used on their current incarnation of [TeamPulse](http://demos.telerik.com/teampulse-demo/), and would like some assistance on setting up a hierarchical menu slider similar to that used on this application.

I have seen a few JS examples, but nothing quite like the one on the Telerik page.

I also have KendoUI, but haven't yet found how to accomplish this.